# angular material generate mat auto complete for different rows in a table

Tags: angular-material-5, mat-autocomplete

I am creating a table using mat -table and I need an auto complete in one column of every row , however when I select a value from auto complete all the rows get populated with same value . The reason for this is the template variable gets set same for each row , is there is a solution to avoid this?

**Image**

[image]

Comment: It would be better if you can provide some code.

Answer (score 0):

Try this: https://chenhaoyork.wordpress.com/2018/09/09/angular-material-table-with-autocomplete-template-driven-form/.

The example shows how to add numerous controls within a table including an autocomplete control.